# how to access database from server and my hosting is linux shared hosting

Tags: mysql, shared-hosting, worklight-adapters, cloud-hosting, worklight-server

I have an Linux shared hosting space. I am trying to connect through the IP of my hosting space to WORK LIGHT server.set the hosting IP in mysql.Xml file. but am Success fully create a app in localhost its working fine in simulator. when am trying to test the app in android device it didn't access the database. please some body help me how to access the database in device.either I need to purchase VIRTUAL PRIVATE DEDICATED SERVERS  to host my app database in those hosting space

Comment: There are a lot of words here, but almost no useful information to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Worklight does not work that way.

You need a host machine on top of which you should have either Tomcat, WebSphere or WebSphere Liberty profile installed. On top of this installation you deploy the Worklight Server (read the documentation).

The IP of the server is the IP of the host machine.

When you build your Worklight-based application, you build it with the IP address mentioned above (read the documentation). When launching the app and attempting to connect to the server/invoking an adapter procedure, the attempt will be done against that IP address.

That's called "on-prem", when you setup the server on your own infrastructure.

You do not try to connect your "remote host" to the "local server".
Frankly, I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Please, stop developing.
Read the documentation, read it.

Knowledge Center: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNJXP/welcome.html
Developer Center: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform